# Ruby Twitter gem: undefined method `each_byte' for nil:NilClass on twitter_client.update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, ruby-on-rails-5

I have wierd problem with gem. It is working perfectly fine in rails console, but from lib/ it isnt

undefined method `each_byte' for nil:NilClass
in a row

```
twitter_client.update(tweet_text.to_s)
def twitter_client
  Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key = credentials[:consumer_key]
    config.consumer_secret = credentials[:consumer_secret]
    config.access_token = credentials[:access_token]
    config.access_token_secret = credentials[:access_token_secret]
    config.user_agent = "TwitterRubyGem/6.2.0"
  end
end
```

full_trace:

```
| 2019-07-23T16:53:21.793Z 64165 TID-oxprcg2np WARN: NoMethodError: undefined method `each_byte' for nil:NilClass
 | 2019-07-23T16:53:21.793Z 64165 TID-oxprcg2np WARN: /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:308:in `block in escape'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:230:in `gsub'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:230:in `gsub'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:305:in `escape'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/simple_oauth-0.3.1/lib/simple_oauth/header.rb:32:in `escape'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/simple_oauth-0.3.1/lib/simple_oauth/header.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in normalized_params'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/simple_oauth-0.3.1/lib/simple_oauth/header.rb:114:in `collect'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/simple_oauth-0.3.1/lib/simple_oauth/header.rb:114:in `block in normalized_params'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/simple_oauth-0.3.1/lib/simple_oauth/header.rb:114:in `collect'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/simple_oauth-0.3.1/lib/simple_oauth/header.rb:114:in `normalized_params'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/simple_oauth-0.3.1/lib/simple_oauth/header.rb:110:in `signature_base'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/simple_oauth-0.3.1/lib/simple_oauth/header.rb:101:in `hmac_sha1_signature'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/simple_oauth-0.3.1/lib/simple_oauth/header.rb:97:in `signature'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/simple_oauth-0.3.1/lib/simple_oauth/header.rb:77:in `signed_attributes'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/simple_oauth-0.3.1/lib/simple_oauth/header.rb:83:in `normalized_attributes'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/simple_oauth-0.3.1/lib/simple_oauth/header.rb:65:in `to_s'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/headers.rb:39:in `auth_header'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/headers.rb:30:in `request_headers'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/rest/request.rb:62:in `set_multipart_options!'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/rest/request.rb:28:in `initialize'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:50:in `new'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:50:in `perform_request'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:72:in `perform_request_with_object'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:64:in `perform_post_with_object'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/rest/tweets.rb:155:in `update!'
 | /Users/DekaKisaLove/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@closedwon/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/rest/tweets.rb:126:in `update'
```

rfc2396_parser.rb:308

```
  def escape(str, unsafe = @regexp[:UNSAFE])
  unless unsafe.kind_of?(Regexp)
    # perhaps unsafe is String object
    unsafe = Regexp.new("[#{Regexp.quote(unsafe)}]", false)
  end
  str.gsub(unsafe) do
    us = $&
    tmp = ''
    us.each_byte do |uc|
      tmp << sprintf('%%%02X', uc)
    end
    tmp
  end.force_encoding(Encoding::US_ASCII)
end
```

Comment: There's no reference to `each_byte` here so you may need to dig down some more.

Comment: @tadman thats the only reference =( cmd+f in log for each_byte are present only in the error message

Comment: It's in the `rfc2396_parser.rb` file on line 308.

Comment: @tadman added to question

Answer (score 1):

Im very sorry, problem was in tweet_text - it CANNOT HAVE special symbols. I hope this helps someone someday... I spent 4 hrs.